# Help with recursing self-referencing table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Datasource ( A self referencing table)
------------------------------
Id, Type, ParentId, Name
1   A     NULL      Foo
2   B     1         Bar
3   C     1         FooBar

Variable
------------------------------------
Id DataSourceId Name
1  3            Foo
2  2            Bar
3  1            Foobar
```

My desired output is something like:

```
Output
---------------------------------------------
VariableId  DataSourceId
1           1
2           1
3           1
```

Such that for each variable, the datasource is the topmost parent in the hierarchy.

I'm struggling with the required recursion of the self referencing table.

Comment: How does (`VariableId = 1`) relate to (`DataSourceId = 1`)?  Your table definitions don't suggest such connection, the example output has it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the recursive CTE to get the tree. Keep track of the parent too (faking the bottom level), to identify when it's null.

```
WITH Tree AS (
    SELECT Id AS VariableId, DataSourceId, DataSourceId AS Parent
    FROM Variable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.VariableId, t.DataSourceId, d.ParentId
    FROM Tree t
    JOIN DataSource d
    ON d.Id = t.Parent
)
--Now get the top levels
SELECT VariableId, DataSourceId
FROM Tree
WHERE Parent IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Rob.  I now get the error saying 'The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.'

Comment: Sorry, typo. `d.Id = t.Parent`

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd part of the union be? `SELECT t.VariableId, ...`

Comment: Ha - yes... that too. I wonder how it worked at all. Serves me right for answering questions on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

The construct you are looking for to get information out of a recursive model like that is a "recursive common table expression". You'll find a number of good explanations here and elsewhere if you search for that term, and there <strike>will no doubt be a concrete example posted as an answer before I've finished typing what is to follow below...</strike> is a concrete example now in Rob Farley's answer.

If you have control of the structure though (i.e. it is your design rather than something you have been given to report from but can't change), I would redesign to make such cleverness querying unnecessary. This can mean a little more work *maintaining* the data but can greatly improve the ease and speed of querying from it.

What you have here is a "simple tree" (what some call a "naive tree") which for simple things is fine (so don't over-engineer by following what I'm about to say if your task is simple enough or the relevant data is small enough the efficiencies don't matter!) but there are other alternatives you could try that make the sort of query you are trying much simpler:

- Store the path to each node as well as its parent so for B in your case that would be /1/2 and if there was a source D under B with id=4 its path would be /1/2/4. Then you can find all nodes under B with `WHERE path LIKE '/1/2/%'` or to include B itself `WHERE path LIKE '/1/2%'`. Remember to index the path column of course. The difficulty here is that if you move nodes in the tree you need to make sure all the affected paths get updated (this is not an issue if things are not moved once created).
- Use a closure table (i.e. store a graph map with distances between nodes) like http://karwin.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html - similarly to the paths this is extra structural data you need to maintain. For some queries both methods work as well, the closure table makes it easier to work at arbitrary depths, and the paths method make tree based ordering easier.
  BTW: the book by Mr Karwin (who's blog I've just linked to) "SQL Antipatterns" is one I recommend anyone from beginner upwards has a scan through, it covers quite a lot of common issues (including trees handling) in a manner a beginner should find approachable while also helping those of us with more experience who should already know better.
- Nested sets is another common method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Of course you are breaking normal form with some of these techniques (storing the simple parent relationships as well as the derived paths, for instance). There are ways to avoid this (making the path to a node its ID for example, MS SQL Server has a built-in type that tries to do just that but more efficiently than encoding path data in strings as IDs yourself: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173(v=sql.110).aspx for details) but they can open up their own complications.

**tl;dr:** *from where you are now a recursive CTE is what you need, like the example in Rob's answer, but you might want to consider a structure that is easier to make tree based queries with.*